# Foreach Parameter of SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm wondering if SQL Server has a way for me to AUTOMATICALLY list all the parameters that my stored procedure contains and then use it in a foreach similar to the below c# code

In C# it would be something like

```
Foreach(Parameter param in StoredProcedure)
{
    if(param.value == "All")
    {
      param.value = "";
    }
}
```

The foreach would obviously be in SQL code.

Comment: sql server is not mysql. Please don't tag irrelevant products.

Comment: @ZoharPeled edited, thank you.

Comment: Sql server does not have a foreach loop. Why do you want this?

Comment: @ZoharPeled As seen in the c# foreach, i need to catch any value that is "All" and change it to ' '

Comment: Pass in the data in a table valued parameter then you can perform set based operations or as a last resort a cursor loop, this is quite an unusual thing to need as SPs cannot be variadic, if you explain why perhaps alternatives can be suggested.

Comment: Anticipating that you need to filter a particular value using like operator i.e. '%<param>%' and want to replace ALL with blank.
You can do same with case statement 
Case When <param>='ALL' Then '' Else <Param> End

Comment: @AlexK.basically I created a filter which filers out data, to date i have been using the VARCHAR ' '  as a default for "select everything, dont filter anything"....My architect wants me to change the ' '  to "All" to make it more readable

Comment: @AlexK. the only problem is that "All" seems to not work with anything but VARCHAR where ' ' works with a multitude of datatypes

Comment: Sounds like they should be `NULL` rather than `''` - if you have mixed types.  In the SP you can `set @param = nullif(@param, 'All')` for the params to get a valid (non `'All'`) value or a `NULL` then use the usual `where (fld = @param or @param is null)`

Comment: @AlexK. yea i have been using (@param = '' OR fld = @param)

Answer (score 1):

You're probably trying to solve the wrong problem here, but - here's the T-SQL statement that will retrieve all parameters for some stored procedure:

```
select * 
from sys.parameters 
where object_id = object_id('procedure_name') 
order by parameter_id
```